# Mule MSMQ flow gives connection refused error in Mule Studio

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, msmqintegrationbinding, mule-component

I'm trying to run the sample example from Mule blog for [MSMQ](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MSMQ+Connector). 
When I setup MSMQ as global component "Test connection" says Successful, that means MSMQ is setup. Well and good till now..
Now using the following flow to test sending a message into queue:

```
<msmq:config name="MSMQ" serviceAddress="machinename/localhost:9000" accessToken="XZodtPym+v6NeZs+Sr4+GK9EGdA=" rootQueueName=".\private$\msmq-demo" doc:name="MSMQ"   >
    <msmq:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</msmq:config>
<flow name="testingFlow1" doc:name="testingFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8091" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[header:INBOUND:http.relative.path]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message=" Sending message: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <msmq:send config-ref="MSMQ" doc:name="MSMQ"/>
</flow>
```

When the flow hits MSMQ in console I see this error:

```
    INFO  2014-08-07 18:00:41,299 [[testing].testingFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:  Sending message: test
    ERROR 2014-08-07 18:00:42,888 [[testing].testingFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: Connection refused: connect. Type: class java.net.ConnectException
    ERROR 2014-08-07 18:00:42,894 [[testing].testingFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke send. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Exception stack is:
    1. Connection refused: connect (java.net.ConnectException)
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
    2. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect (com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException)
    com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler:148 (null)
    3. Failed to invoke send. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
    org.mule.modules.msmq.processors.SendMessageProcessor:198 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
```

Any help or directions is welcome!
msmq-config picture for clarity:
[Test connection succeeds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT1E6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of the pudding is Mule not Studio: if Mule can't connect then Studio most probably can't either, but fails to report the issue.

So you need to fix the `msmq:config` element until it works.

At first glance, this `serviceAddress="machinename/localhost:9000"` looks highly suspicious. You should either use the actual machine name and port or `localhost` and port if running collocated with MSMQ.

Comment: Machine name I purposefully changed it for privacy.In msmq global element wizard.after pressing Test connection it succeeds but when I run it in flow it fails.

Comment: Hi David, when I changed the inbound http-component to request-reply I got a message saying:"Failed to invoke send. Message payload is of type: String".. Is there a clue here?? Must I use POST instead of GET request?

Comment: It's just another side effect of the connection failing. And as I said, the fact Studio says it's working doesn't necessarily mean it is. If Mule says it's not, Mule is right. Can you successfully telnet to the host and port you've configured in `msmq:config`?

Comment: Hi David, Why the value of Host address in <appSettings> has a '+' sign..Do I have to replace it with 'localhost'?
    <!-- Configure the serivce to listen on the following address. -->
    <add key="OwinHostAddress" value="https://+:9000/"/>...

Comment: Replace it with the relevant host name where the MSMQ broker is listening on port 9000. If it's localhost, then use localhost. If it's a remote host use the host name.

Comment: Thanks David, I wanted to confirm it, after all the attempts I am getting connection refused. Am I only one in the world trying to test run the Mule MSMQ connector?

Comment: This interrop with Microsoft technologies is still quite new so maybe there are not many people using it yet? Maybe the best is to contact MuleSoft directly,

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:msmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/msmq" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/msmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/msmq/current/mule-msmq.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <msmq:config name="MSMQ" serviceAddress="x.x.x.:9333" accessToken="wRuoma0PhX4ZHA1vQosdefff="  rootQueueName=".\private$\msmqdemo" ignoreSSLWarnings="true" doc:name="MSMQ"/>
    <flow name="msmqreceiveFlow">
       <set-payload value="Hello" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <msmq:send config-ref="MSMQ__MSMQ_Connection" queueName="msmqdemo" doc:name="MSMQ"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Try this example I think service address is wrong.This example for sending  message to MSMQ queue